# Configuring GA4 to Display Aggregate Traffic on Filtered Pages, Similar to Universal Analytics

Tags: universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

In GA4, I want to have a graph showing the total visits on certain pages that I have filtered.

With Universal Analytics, when you went to 'Behavior', 'Site Content', 'All Pages', it was possible to see the traffic on all pages. You could filter the pages according to our choice, and the graph would display the traffic for all these pages.

With GA4, I can't seem to get this information anymore. I've created an exploration, putting 'path' as the dimension and total number of users as the metric, but the graphical result shows up page by page and not as a grouping of all the pages.

What is the correct configuration to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `Free Form` Exploration method.

Starting in the variables pane, click the `+` next to dimensions and select some sort of page identifier (`Page Path`, `Page Location`, `Page Title`, etc) that will be used to filter down to your desired pages.

Scroll down and next to metrics click the `+` and select `views`.

In the settings pane, under `values`, click the `+` and add the `views` metric from the previous step.

From here, there is nothing else to do. You should see a `Total Views` column in the table to the right that will show all the views for all your pages.

At the bottom of the settings pane, there are filter options where you can add a filter to look at specific pages and/or groups of pages.

Of course there are other things you can use for dimensions (such as `date`) rather than leaving it blank that that would give you better insights into the traffic to those pages. But this is dependent on your/your client's need.